# No such file or directory, NSFilePath=~/Library

Tags: ios, swift, sandbox, nsfilemanager, nslibrarydirectory

The below quoted error gets thrown when I run the following code snippet

```
fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(libraryPath)
```

Error

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (Cocoa error 260.)" UserInfo=0x17585bf0
>   {NSUnderlyingError=0x175706b0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No
>   such file or directory", NSFilePath=~/Library, NSUserStringVariant=(
>       Folder )}

Here is the complete code snippet that I used just in case if anybody wants to try

```
   func listLibDir(){

        let libraryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.LibraryDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, false).first!

        let fileManager: NSFileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

        do{
            var directoryContent:Array<String> = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(libraryPath)

            for fileName: String in directoryContent {
                print("library:\(fileName)")
            }
        }
        catch{
            print(error)
        }

    }
```

If somebody can clarify why this error happens and suggest a solution then it'd be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code:

```
let libraryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.LibraryDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, false).first!
```

Set the permission to `true`:

```
let libraryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.LibraryDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true).first
```

Comment: To add a bit of the "why" part....  Tilde expansion is usually done by the command line shell, so if you were passing the result to an external command or just displaying the result, `false` would be fine.  The file manager routines don't do the expansion automatically.